# Is it possible to use Pagoda Box with AWS data?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-s3, pagoda-box

My data lives on an AWS S3 instance, I'm (considering) deploying an website  on Pagoda Box.  Is it possible to configure my instance so it reads and writes data from S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access S3 from PagodaBox

- Create a IAM user under your AWS account and add the policy allowing access to your S3 buckets.
- Generate and note down the access key and secret for the user.
- Using the the access key, secret and [AWS PHP SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingTheMPphpAPI.html) in your PagodaBox application, you can access S3 content.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact, that the Amazon S3 has a web service interface, you could do this with REST-Services.